# Windows 32 or 64 bit using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432 Node

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm looking for a very simple way of determining if the version of Windows the customer is using is 32bit or 64bit. I know there are ways using .NEt but I'm looking to avoid them. I simply want to use something similar the below pseudo code and want to know if this method can be reliable.

```
If Registry Key exists (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node)
   Then Assume 64bit
else
   Assume 32bit
```

Thanks!

EDIT: To be more specific, I know there a several different ways to accomplish the goal of finding out if the OS is 32 or 64bit. But I want to know if the above alone method would be reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not check for the existence of the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)`? This will assure you that it's a 64bit OS.

Comment: ...unless some program created it as part of its install, even though it installed on a 32-bit machine. :-)

Comment: very unlikely but possible ^^

Comment: ... or you are running on a localized version of windows

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are running in a 32-bit process (otherwise you would already know the answer).  The solution to your problem is either [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx) or [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the environment variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE. If it is AMD64 then you are on a 64 bit OS, but this is not safe (after reading comments)

But to be safe, you can call an Win32 API, IsWow64Process as mentioned in this  [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx) from [Raymond Chen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Chen).

Comment: ...unless the script is running in c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe, where is defined as *PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86* and there's a separate *PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64*

Answer (score 0):

i hope this can solve the problem i tried it on my windows 8.1 64 bit and it  returns the value AMD64 for me

```
import _winreg
def get_registry_value(key, subkey, value):

  key = getattr(_winreg, key)
  handle = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey )
  (value, type) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(handle, value)
  return value

windowsbit = get_registry_value(
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE",
"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment",
"PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
print windowsbit
```

just run this code if you are working on 64 bit windows machine this will print AMD64

or if you are working on 32 bit it will print AMD32

i hope this code can help to solve this problem fully